# Spacy Not running on GPU in windows 11

Tags: python-3.x, gpu, spacy-3

I installed spacy using `pip install spacy[cuda122]`,
while doing `spacy.require_gpu()` it is returning **True**

My nvcc --version returns

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jun_13_19:42:34_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.2, V12.2.91
Build cuda_12.2.r12.2/compiler.32965470_0
```

I am trying to run a NER pipeline on custom data, however, spacy is throwing an error.

The error looks like:

```
CompileException: `nvcc` command returns non-zero exit status. 
command: ['C:\\Program', 'Files\\NVIDIA', 'GPU', 'Computing', 'Toolkit\\CUDA\\v12.2\\bin\\nvcc.EXE', '-gencode=arch=compute_86,code=sm_86', '--ptx', '-DFIRST_PASS=1', '--std=c++11', '-IC:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\cupy\\_core\\include', '-IC:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\cupy\\_core\\include\\cupy\\_cuda\\cuda-12', '-IC:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v12.2\\include', '-ftz=true', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpuyh6r3n0\\preprocess.cu']
return-code: 1
stdout/stderr: 
nvcc fatal   : Cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH
```

From the error i can understand that some exe file is missing in path, but i cannot find that.
I tried searching for the solution but didn't understand what to do.

Answer (score 0):

It Turns out I had to install Visual Studio with C++ development so that cl.exe gets installed and added to the path.